# Xcode 4.2 thread 1 sigabrt error. Retrieving from Database

Tags: sqlite, xcode4.2, sigabrt

I found out that Sigabrt throws error because of this code where am trying to retrieve from database based on a tutorial but I dont know what the error is. I just commented the lines that gave me problem but am not understanding what is happening though

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
    MyWineLists * mywines =[[MyWineLists alloc] init];
    self.wines = [mywines getMyWines];
    /*[self.wineViewer setImage:((WineList *) [self.wines objectAtIndex:0]).photo];

    [self.winename setText:((WineList *) [self.wines objectAtIndex:0]).wine];

    [self.winerating setText:((WineList *) [self.wines objectAtIndex:0]).rating];*/
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: You may want to post a link to the CS4521 SQLite thingy so everyone knows what you're talking about. I've seen other programmers who don't have the skills to find this, so don't think because I did, others will.

Comment: I dont get what you say but the issue is solved now I was not giving correct column name in my select query